# WordPress + Admin Panel + Plugin Page + AJAX = 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, wordpress

There is a plugin page with this code:

```
<?php

function my_action() {
check_admin_referrer();
echo(json_encode( array('status'=>'ok','request_vars'=>$_REQUEST) ));
wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');


if (isset($_POST['my_action']))
if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'my_action' ) ) my_action();

?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: "my_action",
            //"nonce" : "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_action' ); ?>"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('AJAX response : ',response);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

When executed on the page the plugin returns
**400 Bad Request**
Although the action parameters of the request is set

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this code working fine.

Comment: It does not work for me
WP installed on the VPS, maybe some additional settings are needed?